# Помогите понять работу с файлами

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь создать файл с неким выводом программы. FileOutputStream.openFileOutput берет в аргумент путь к создаваемому файлу. Но как я узнаю папку программы. На тестируемом телефоне я, как ни пытался, не смог найти папку своей программы. Так что же указывать в качестве пути к файлу?
Я попытался указать просто имя файла. Вот так:

```
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("samplefile.txt",  MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Но приложение в таком случае не работает. Что я сделал не так?

Comment: а как вы файл создаете, вы ему путь пишете вообще? покажите немного больше кода

Comment: `openFileOutput()` создаёт файл во внутренней памяти устройства в приватной папке приложения и доступ к нему будет только у вашего приложения - поэтому увидеть его через файловый менеджер или другое приложение не получится, но можно через [Device File Explorer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer) в студии.